# NextUI - SSRProvider not recognized by application

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, nextui

I am trying to implement NextUI into my react app. Although I have added the `SSRProvider` component I still receive the following error:

`You must wrap your application in an SSRProvider to ensure consistent ids are generated between the client and server`.

Here is my code I have added to my app file.

```
import "@/styles/globals.css";

import { SSRProvider } from "@react-aria/ssr";
import { NextUIProvider } from "@nextui-org/react";

import Layout from "@/components/Layout";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <SSRProvider>
      <NextUIProvider>
        <Layout>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
      </NextUIProvider>
    </SSRProvider>
  );
}
```